# Azure-AD-B2C Token format

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have built a service that calls cosmos DB for custom claims to be sent in ID token. The output of the REST API is as per the expected token format below

```
{"personalAttributes":{"guid":"1b92e96e28b14737acac11d23dcdd3d0","familyName":"ABC","givenName":"PQR","name":"PQR","preferredUserName":"PQR","upn":"PQR@XYZ.com",
"physicalLocation":"London, UK"
"roles":"Engineer","Engineer","Engineer",
"scopes":{"scopeName":"Application 2 - Pipe Spool install","initiative":"nan","operation":"nan","WBS":"nan"},
{"roleName":"Engineer","jobPosition":"Engineer","rolePermissions":"read, report, archive"},
{"roleName":"Engineer","jobPosition":"Engineer","rolePermissions":"read, report, archive"},
{"roleName":"Engineer","jobPosition":"Engineer","rolePermissions":"read, report, archive"}}
```

However, when B2C includes this in the ID Token it is appending / and . We tried formatting the output which is resulting in B2C not even generating the ID token. PLease advise how we can overcome this

TIA

Comment: Hello @Sri, can you share the B2C id token?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Below is the B2C formatted token. Please advise how to remove the special characters

Comment: "personalAttributes": [
    "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"guid\": [\r\n      \"1b92e96e28b14737acacaaa23dcdd3d0\"\r\n    ],\r\n    \"familyName\": [\r\n      \"ABC\"\r\n    ],\r\n    \"givenName\": [\r\n      \"PQR\"\r\n    ],
 \r\n    \"name\": [\r\n      \"ABC\"\r\n    ],\r\n    \"preferredUserName\": [\r\n      \"PQR\"\r\n    ],
 \r\n    \"upn\": [\r\n      \"PQR@XYZ.com\"\r\n    ],\r\n    \"physicalLocation\": [\r\n      \"London, UK\"\r\n    ],

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to ask B2C to output a complex object as a claim value. This isn't supported so B2C casting the object to a string - resulting the escaped JSON data you are seeing.

Edit for additional clarity: The `personalAttributes` value returned from CosmosDB is not a StringCollection (array) as you have defined in the ClaimsSchema. It is a JSON object. B2C does not support object claim types - you'll need to extract the exact values you want from the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a [GetClaimFromJson transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimfromjson) to extract claims from JSON.

Comment: We tried this and it seems the policy is not providing any output as we're looping constantly at the authentication. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sri do you mean being constantly redirected to the login form? can you share your policies?

Comment: the policy is too big to add in the comment section. ANyway i can upload it?

Comment: @Sri provided it does not content confidential information you can upload it to a github repo and share it here.

Comment: @Sri apologies I posted the wrong transformation. I've updated my answer. Also your code snippets are calling GetClaimsFromJsonArray which won't work

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: @Sri extract each claim from each api json attribute (eg: personalAttributes) using GetClaimFromJson.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_oboTrustFrameworkExtensions" PublicPolicyUri="http://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_oboTrustFrameworkExtensions" TenantObjectId="3dc9a24f-ed39-4635-b182-e35aadde9cb2">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>xxxx.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_oboTrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="clientId">
        <DisplayName>OIDC client id</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="personalAttributes">
        <DisplayName>Custom claim</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="roles">
        <DisplayName>Custom claim</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="scopes">
        <DisplayName>Custom claim</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="tokenOwner">
        <DisplayName>aud claim in OBO token</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="jsonSourceClaim">
        <DisplayName>JSON output from Custom Service</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="GetClaimsFromJson">
        <DisplayName>JSON output from Custom Service</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertClientIdAndAudAreEqual" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenOwner" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
        </InputParameters>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetClaimsFromJsonTransformation" TransformationMethod="GetClaimsFromJsonArray">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jsonSourceClaim" TransformationClaimType="jsonSource" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="errorOnMissingClaims" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
          <InputParameter Id="includeEmptyClaims" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
          <InputParameter Id="jsonSourceKeyName" DataType="string" Value="key" />
          <InputParameter Id="jsonSourceValueName" DataType="string" Value="value" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="personalAttributes" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="roles" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scopes" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <!-- Used for custom extension attribute storage -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">xxxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="ClientId">xxxxxx</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>bechtel</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Bechtel AAD</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Bechtel-AAD">
          <DisplayName>Work or school account</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login with your work or school account</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
            <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/22d635a3-3930-4779-a82d-155e2d13b75e</Item>
            <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
            <!--<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item> -->
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_BECHTELSECRET" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <!--OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" /-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="bechtel" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">facebook_clientid</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">db6c8fe9-368f-48a0-af63-19ad47d91e90</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">5169b8e9-5bcd-4b04-b5f1-d3ca801bbbef</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="db6c8fe9-368f-48a0-af63-19ad47d91e90" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="5169b8e9-5bcd-4b04-b5f1-d3ca801bbbef" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetCustomClaim">
          <DisplayName>Get a custom claim</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <!--<Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://beciamobo.azurewebsites.net/CustomClaims</Item> -->
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/xxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Scope}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="personalAttributes" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="roles" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scopes" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetClaimsFromJsonTransformation" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ValidateOBORequest">
          <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenOwner" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenOwner" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertClientIdAndAudAreEqual" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SUSI">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AADExchange" />
            <!--ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" /-->
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <!--ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges-->
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <!--Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions-->
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Bechtel-AAD" />
            <!--ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" /-->
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <!--Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions-->
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
            from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
            (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetCustomClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetCustomClaim" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
    <UserJourney Id="OBO">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Validate" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ValidateOBORequest" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetCustomClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetCustomClaim" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you _edit_ your answer to provide additional explanation about what you've included here? Where should the OP place this XML? How does this solve this problem? If there a specific element or attribute that mitigates the original issue? As is, just dumping a large XML configuration without explanation will likely lead to more questions, and won't help educate readers facing this problem about how to solve similar issues in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see policy below

```html
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_oboTrustFrameworkExtensions" PublicPolicyUri="http://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_oboTrustFrameworkExtensions" TenantObjectId="3dc9a24f-ed39-4635-b182-e35aadde9cb2">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>xxxx.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_oboTrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="clientId">
        <DisplayName>OIDC client id</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="personalAttributes">
        <DisplayName>Custom claim</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="roles">
        <DisplayName>Custom claim</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="scopes">
        <DisplayName>Custom claim</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="tokenOwner">
        <DisplayName>aud claim in OBO token</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="jsonSourceClaim">
        <DisplayName>JSON output from Custom Service</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="GetClaimsFromJson">
        <DisplayName>JSON output from Custom Service</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertClientIdAndAudAreEqual" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenOwner" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
        </InputParameters>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetClaimsFromJsonTransformation" TransformationMethod="GetClaimsFromJsonArray">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jsonSourceClaim" TransformationClaimType="jsonSource" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="errorOnMissingClaims" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
          <InputParameter Id="includeEmptyClaims" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
          <InputParameter Id="jsonSourceKeyName" DataType="string" Value="key" />
          <InputParameter Id="jsonSourceValueName" DataType="string" Value="value" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="personalAttributes" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="roles" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scopes" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <!-- Used for custom extension attribute storage -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">xxxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="ClientId">xxxxxx</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>bechtel</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Bechtel AAD</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Bechtel-AAD">
          <DisplayName>Work or school account</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login with your work or school account</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
            <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/22d635a3-3930-4779-a82d-155e2d13b75e</Item>
            <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
            <!--<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item> -->
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_BECHTELSECRET" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <!--OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" /-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="bechtel" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">facebook_clientid</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">db6c8fe9-368f-48a0-af63-19ad47d91e90</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">5169b8e9-5bcd-4b04-b5f1-d3ca801bbbef</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="db6c8fe9-368f-48a0-af63-19ad47d91e90" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="5169b8e9-5bcd-4b04-b5f1-d3ca801bbbef" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetCustomClaim">
          <DisplayName>Get a custom claim</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <!--<Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://beciamobo.azurewebsites.net/CustomClaims</Item> -->
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/xxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Scope}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="personalAttributes" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="roles" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scopes" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetClaimsFromJsonTransformation" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ValidateOBORequest">
          <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenOwner" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenOwner" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertClientIdAndAudAreEqual" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SUSI">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AADExchange" />
            <!--ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" /-->
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <!--ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges-->
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <!--Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions-->
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Bechtel-AAD" />
            <!--ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" /-->
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <!--Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions-->
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
            from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
            (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetCustomClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetCustomClaim" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
    <UserJourney Id="OBO">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Validate" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ValidateOBORequest" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetCustomClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetCustomClaim" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```